# Num Lock Key Randomly Turning On and Off

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, 15.10, numlock

First time caller, long time listener.

I have been using Mint for a few years and have recently switched to Ubuntu.  Everything was great until I purchased a newer laptop.  With this laptop, number Lock seems to turn itself off and on randomly.  When this happens, the functionality of "0", "p", ";", "/" change to "/", "*", "-", "+" respectively.  This presents a problem when one tries to type the word python into a terminal.  I found that holding the function key and pressing the desired key will produce a desired result.  I have a few questions:
1. How do I toggle Num Lock on a Keyboard without a key designated as such.
2. While I am typing, the computer seemingly randomly will turn Num Lock on or off without apparent reason.  Why?
3. Is there a long term fix for this problem?  (Set Num Lock to always off or fix the bug )

My specs:
Laptop = Asus Q301LA-BSI5T17 ( this model does not have a number pad or Num Lock key)
Running Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
Keyboard Layout: Default English (US) ( this is the only layout I have installed as an option )

Laptop ran fine for a few weeks after the install.  Problem started 2 days ago and randomly comes and goes.  The problem persists through the whole OS, not just the terminal.  If I go to All Settings>Text Input and click the keyboard icon under "Input Sources to Use", I can see whether or not Num Lock is selected.  This is how I determined that was the problem.

Edit: To accomplish Number 1 from terminal:

```
apt-get install numlockx
/usr/bin/numlockx off
```

Comment: Any thoughts on why this is happening??? I really would appreciate any help available.

Comment: Same with Asus GL702ZC. ubuntu 17.10.1 fresh install.

Comment: I don't have my Asus that was giving me problems, but my solution was similar to this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock . (As I recall)

Comment: It's happening on HP 250 5G with Linux Mint too.